# tex4ht: reuse png images instead of creating new ones

Tags: graphics, tex4ht

I have a lot of PNG images in my document, which (the document) I'd like to convert to HTML using tex4ht (`htlatex`). Now the images need to be in EPS format, as `htlatex` uses DVI mode. So I run `convert foo.png foo.eps` before I run `htlatex`. When generating the HTML, tex4ht creates a new PNG out of these EPS images, although I have the original which could (should) be used instead. That would save me quite some time and space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\section{something}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{mill}
\end{document}
```

(`mill.png` is from the ConTeXt distribution, but could be any PNG file.)

Comment: I thought it was not so much DVI-mode that requires eps, but the latex command itself. pdflatex can also output dvi by using `-output-format=dvi`but I don't know if it helps in this situation.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman that's an interesting thought, I'll do some research on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide extension for your graphics file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\section{something}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{mill.png}
\end{document}
```

This compiles fine without need for the eps step

Comment: But png files do not have bounding box? the width will be ignored when run by tex4ht, and original .png size will be used. I tried it on texlive 2013. Only pdflatex will scale the .png file, but not tex4ht

Answer (score 4):

I feel stupid, but I can answer my own question. With the following configuration file, `htlatex` uses EPS and `pdflatex` uses PNG:

```
\Preamble{html}
\begin{document}

 \Configure{graphics*}
         {eps}
         {\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt}}

\EndPreamble
```

Save this file in `whatever.cfg` and call tex4ht with `htlatex myfile whatever`.