# tex4ht: create (dummy) eps images on the fly

Tags: graphics, tex4ht

I am using tex4ht to create a document in HTML and my images are PNG files. For tex4ht I need eps images although in the final HTML page I use original PNG files (see my [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43391/tex4ht-reuse-png-images-instead-of-creating-new-ones) here on tex.se).

So the idea is to use a dummy eps image of a certain width and height (the size should not matter, as the final image is replaced anyway).

---

The current situation is the following: for every PNG image, I need an EPS image with the same name, for `htlatex` (DVI mode) to find it. The EPS is never visible to the user, it is only used internally. So IMO it is not really necessary. I would like to avoid the extra steps to create the EPS file and the double disk space (I use a lot of images).

Comment: see my answer for your original question

Comment: @michal.h21 can you turn your comment into an answer? It is a short answer, but it is the one I'd accept (according to the rule that the one that I use is the one I accept, even if there are longer/more technical/better answers). It is so simple that it works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From (@michal.h21) the question linked in the post:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\section{something}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{mill.png}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't use eps images.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines

```
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{htlatex}}%
        {\oldincludegraphics{dummyeps}}%
        {\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
```

If you want to be able to adjust the size of the eps graphics, you could redefine `\includegraphics` with two additional arguments that set the `height` and the `width` attributes of `\oldincludegraphics` with `htlatex` but are discarded when compiling with `pdflatex`.