# PDF image files and `htlatex`

Tags: pdf, eps, html, tex4ht

When `eps` files are provided, `htlatex` from `tex4ht` automatically converts to `png` files so that graphic files can be shown in the final `html` output. However, I use most of the time the `pdf` graphic file format with `pdflatex`. Is there any easy way to make `htlatex` work for `pdf` graphic files?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43391/tex4ht-reuse-png-images-instead-of-creating-new-ones

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
  \Configure{graphics*}  
         {pdf}  
         {\Needs{"convert '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf'  
                               '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png'"}%  
          \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}%  
          \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
         }  
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

save it as `myxhtml.cfg`. This configuration tells htlatex for every image file with pdf suffix, run imagemagick's convert command and then insert the image. You must provide correct file extension for every included image in your source file. Compile the file with command

```
htlatex filename myxhtml
```

**Edit**:
Added `\special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}`, purpose of this line is to store information about used images to the `filename.lg` file. This information is important when generated files are copied to another directory (`make4ht` or `tex4ebook` are using this information, for example).

Comment: It works very good. One note: I typically do not specify the graphic file's extension in the `\includegraphics` statement. However, for the `myxhtml.cfg`, I needed to specify, for example `\includegraphics{filename.pdf}`. Or, I can declare in the front: `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}`.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: htlatex needs to know the filename extension, so you have to specify it either in each \includegraphics or widt \DeclareGraphicsExtensions

Comment: @michal.h21: Are you aware of [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75277/8057)?

Comment: For reference: `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}` can be added to `myxhtml.cfg` between `\begin{document}` and `\EndPreamble`.

Comment: @michal.h21: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with oolatex, MWE: https://github.com/muelleki/lm-template/tree/oolatex-pdf-png (check out using Git or download a ZIP file, run `make texput.odt` or `mk4ht oolatex texput "my,ooffice,bib-"`). The `convert` is carried out _after_ zipping the `.odt` file. In the file `texput.lg`, the `File:` entries come just before the `needs` entry. Any way to fix this short of running the compilation twice?

Comment: @user946850 I can't see solution here. maybe by creating script similar to `htlatex`, where `tex4ht` command is called twice - first run for image conversion, the second run for packing `odt` file with `-p` option to avoid image conversion

Comment: @michal.h21 actually `t4ht` command should be called twice.

Comment: @michal.h21: No, unfortunately this doesn't suffice.

Comment: Any tweaks to handle filenames with escaped characters such as "(" or ")"?

Comment: @TomKelly could you post it as a new question with some example?

Comment: Thanks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369176/pdf-image-files-and-htlatex-with-escaped-characters-in-filenames

Answer (score 4):

Based on michal.h21's answer I have derived a solution that accepts (almost) all image types also accepted by default `pdflatex`. This considerably simplifies conversion of documents that are originally created in a `pdflatex`-based environment, as no conversion to EPS is required anymore.

PDFs are converted to PNG files with a density of 300 dpi. (I couldn't get SVG to work properly with LibreOffice, perhaps Enhanced Metafile or Windows Metafile could work, too, if Microsoft Word is your final target platform.) PNGs and JPEGs are used as they are, for the latter the extension is always `.jpg`.
I have also added support for images in other than the default location by implementing a similar naming scheme to the one used by `tex4ht` for autogenerated images.

The process requires the following configuration file, let's call it `my.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
  \newcommand{\ConfigureGraphicsDirect}[3]{%
    \Configure{graphics*}
         {#1}
         {\Needs{"#3 \csname Gin@base\endcsname.#1
                               \jobname\arabic{texforhtimagecounter}y.#2"}%
          \Picture[pict]{\jobname\arabic{texforhtimagecounter}y.#2}%
          \stepcounter{texforhtimagecounter}%
         }%
  }
  \ConfigureGraphicsDirect{pdf}{png}{convert -density 300}%
  \ConfigureGraphicsDirect{png}{png}{cp}%
  \ConfigureGraphicsDirect{jpg}{jpg}{cp}%
  \ConfigureGraphicsDirect{jpeg}{jpg}{cp}%
\begin{document}
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.jpeg}
  \newcounter{texforhtimagecounter}
  \renewcommand{\AsPicture}[1]{%
    \Picture+[]{}#1\EndPicture}
\EndPreamble
```

For some reason two runs of `mk4ht` are required to produce a complete `.odt` file. After the first run, the images are missing. To compile, type:

```
mk4ht oolatex mainfile "my,ooffice"
mk4ht oolatex mainfile "my,ooffice"
```

For consistent dimensioning of other `\Picture`s, it is worthwhile to use a custom `tex4ht.env` file. I have found that `dvips`+`convert` does a better job here than `dvipng`. For this, copy the `tex4ht.env` file on your system to your main TeX file's directory and substitute this line

```
Gdvipng -T tight -x 1400 -D 72 -bg Transparent -pp %%2:%%2 %%1 -o %%3
```

(starting with `Gdvipng` line just after `G.png`) by:

```
Gdvips -E -D 300 -pp %%2:%%2 %%1 -o %%3.ps
Gconvert -density 300 %%3.ps %%3
```

If LibreOffice/OpenOffice is your target you need to manually resize each figure to 32% (for 300 dpi pictures). I haven't found an automatic way to do this, a modification of `xtpipes` might be required here.

Of course, for this to work on Windows you need to substitute `cp` by `copy` in the corresponding `\ConfigureGraphicsDirect` invocations.

The [complete code](https://github.com/muelleki/lm-template/tree/oolatex-pdf) is at GitHub, however you still might have to use your own copy of tex4ht.env unless you run Ubuntu 12.10 (or later) with a default installation or TeXlive.

I have found a very similar `.cfg` file at http://people.bath.ac.uk/cspehj/maths-access/xht/, but no description whatsoever.

GIF support is left as exercise for the reader.

Comment: I get the error `AsPicture undefined in 'my.cfg'`.

Comment: @mmj: With what command line?

Comment: Both with `mk4ht oolatex mainfile "my,ooffice"` and `htlatex mainfile my`.

Comment: It's been a while. From what I see now, `\AsPicture` is a user-defined command to add any LaTeX material as a picture. It should work if you define `\AsPicture` in your document's preamble, or completely omit the definition. The former is necessary so that the document also works when compiling to PDF.

Comment: actually, `\AsPicture` error catches me too.