# Want to use PDFLaTeX in htlatex comand

Tags: pdftex, tex4ht, html

My document is based on `PDFLaTeX`, if I run the `TeX` application file through `PDFLaTeX`, then I don't have any issues, but if I run the same file for `HTML` conversion through `TeX4ht`, then the following error comes:

[image]

My code is follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

This is for test

\end{document}
```

Note that I am using MikTeX V2.9 and the conversion command is used as:

```
htlatex test "xhtml,fn-in" " -cunifht" "-cvalidate -p"
```

Also note that for the whole project most of the figures are in .pdf format and some of the images are in `.jpg` and `.png` format and very few in .eps format, hence I have used `epstopdf.sty`...
Please suggest...

Comment: Isn't htlatex working on the dvi file? Not pdf?

Comment: Remove option pdftex for graphicx. It doesn't do anything really usefull.

Comment: Sorry, but some of the figures are in PDF format, I didn't include that...

Comment: Please give a minimal working example of your issue. We can't check much without that. Besides this, I'm never naming the driver. Does it work if you remove `[pdftex]` ?

Comment: `htlatex` can work with `PDF` images, but it needs to be configured for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for my requirement and the link is [PDF image files and `htlatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46156/pdf-image-files-and-htlatex/46210) Special Thanks to Michal....